# Custom Attribute not saving on Product

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom-attributes

I've created **two custom attributes**, but when i create a simple product, **just saves one attribute**. Using postman,the request has both attributes fields, but the response just has one. Any help is appreciated.

Color Attribute, this one works.

```
"is_wysiwyg_enabled": false,
"is_html_allowed_on_front": false,
"used_for_sort_by": false,
"is_filterable": true,
"is_filterable_in_search": false,
"is_used_in_grid": true,
"is_visible_in_grid": false,
"is_filterable_in_grid": true,
"position": 0,
"apply_to": [
    "simple",
    "virtual",
    "configurable"
],
"is_searchable": "1",
"is_visible_in_advanced_search": "1",
"is_comparable": "1",
"is_used_for_promo_rules": "0",
"is_visible_on_front": "0",
"used_in_product_listing": "0",
"is_visible": true,
"scope": "global",
"attribute_id": 93,
"attribute_code": "color",
"frontend_input": "select",
"entity_type_id": "4",
"is_required": false,
"options": [
    {
        "label": " ",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "label": "BLACK",
        "value": "5432"
    },
   
    {
        "label": "RATO",
        "value": "5442"
    },
    {
        "label": "WHITE",
        "value": "5438"
    },{
        "label": "CELESTE",
        "value": "5444"
    }
],
"is_user_defined": true,
"default_frontend_label": "Color",
"frontend_labels": [],
"backend_type": "int",
"source_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Table",
"default_value": "5466",
"is_unique": "0",
"validation_rules": []
```

**sizee** attribute, doesn't saves.

```
 "is_wysiwyg_enabled": false,
"is_html_allowed_on_front": false,
"used_for_sort_by": false,
"is_filterable": true,
"is_filterable_in_search": false,
"is_used_in_grid": true,
"is_visible_in_grid": false,
"is_filterable_in_grid": true,
"position": 0,
"apply_to": [
    "simple",
    "virtual",
    "configurable"
],
"is_searchable": "1",
"is_visible_in_advanced_search": "1",
"is_comparable": "1",
"is_used_for_promo_rules": "0",
"is_visible_on_front": "0",
"used_in_product_listing": "0",
"is_visible": true,
"scope": "global",
"attribute_id": 150,
"attribute_code": "sizee",
"frontend_input": "select",
"entity_type_id": "4",
"is_required": false,
"options": [
    {
        "label": " ",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "label": " ",
        "value": "5489"
    },
    {
        "label": " ",
        "value": "5487"
    },
    {
        "label": " ",
        "value": "5488"
    },
    {
        "label": "28",
        "value": "5485"
    },
    {
        "label": "29",
        "value": "5486"
    },
    
    {
        "label": "34",
        "value": "5472"
    }
],
"is_user_defined": true,
"default_frontend_label": "sizee",
"frontend_labels": [],
"backend_type": "int",
"source_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Table",
"default_value": "",
"is_unique": "0",
"validation_rules": []
```

SIMPLE PRODUCT REQUEST:

```
{
        "product": {
            "sku": "hudson02-CELESTE-29",
            "name": "hudson02-CELESTE-29",
            "attribute_set_id": 4,
            "price": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 1,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "stock_item": {
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 888,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
            },
            "product_links": [],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "cnpj",
                    "value": "333"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "ean",
                    "value": "hudson02-CELESTE-29"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "hudson02-CELESTE-29"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_title",
                    "value": "hudson02-CELESTE-29"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
                    "value": "hudson02-CELESTE-29"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "meta_description",
                    "value": "hudson02-CELESTE-29"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": []
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "color",
                    "value": "5444"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "sizee",
                    "value": "5486"
                }
                
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, i looked at the admin menu -> stores -> attribute set, and the custom attribute was unsigned. so i passed it to signed.

Comment: Are you able to put more description on what you did to resolve this issue? alternatively, we can also delete this question if you prefer?

Comment: Actually i solved this on the attribute set, i was using default attribute set, but the "size" attribute was unsigned, so it wasn't working and isn't calculating the attribute to the product, so i turned the attribute to "Signed" and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code so we can see how you create the two custom attributes.

are the two attributes different from each other? maybe one is text/select/multiselect etc.

We can't help you without the related code or specific informations.

docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/

Cheers

Comment: Hey, i updated the question with the codes, have a look.